# How to make text pane accept pastes but block typing

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

My Goal is :
having a text pane where user can paste text only(with OS not a button!!!) **and can't type in to the pane**

because: can't have submit button (this is a must requirement - I know that it's not logical)

after pasting: the text-pane becomes not editable for user, and the program will change background at specific chars.

after button "clear filed" pressed  - the program clears the pane and returns to initial state

My Problem:  How to make text pane accept pastes but block typing

so far I made only JPanel with the text pane itself and all the controls will be in different JPanel

```
public class textPanel extends JPanel{

private JTextPane text;

public textPanel ()
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    text = new JTextPane();        //12,81
    text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    add(text,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    StyledDocument doc = text.getStyledDocument();


    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 210));




}
```

thanks for help

Comment: You might try a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Comment: Why not make it nonfocusable via `setFocusable(false)`. If the component can't receive focus, there will be no way to type into it.

Comment: I tried setFocusable(false) you can't type but also can't paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `public void paste()` method of your. By default your JTextPane is not editable (setEditable(false)).

The `paste()` method's source in `JTextComponent` is

```
public void paste() {
    if (isEditable() && isEnabled()) {
        invokeAction("paste", TransferHandler.getPasteAction());
    }
}
```

So you just make it editable, call `super.paste()`, and set the editable=false back after the super call.